# retrieve and show a specific value via jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-web-api

I need some help, I'm consuming a Web Api service from a MVC ASP.NET App using the jQuery' function $.ajax and need to retrieve a specific record from database, I can connect to the service and retrieve the correct value according to the id provided but I can manage to show the result in a table, I have checked the properties names and all is good, this is my javascript code

```
 $("#boton_de_pabletoreto2").click(function () {
            var id = $("#busqueda").val();
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "http://localhost:55987/api/Empleado/"+ id,
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    if (data != null)
                    {
                        $.each(data, function (i, item) {
                            var rows = "<tr>" +
                                "<td id='id'>" + item.id + "</td>" +
                                "<td id='nombres'>" + item.Nombres + "</td>" +
                                "<td id='cargo'>" + item.Cargo + "</td>" +
                                "<td id='dpto'>" + item.Dpto + "</td>" +
                                "</tr>";
                            $('#Table').append(rows);
                        });
                        console.log(data);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        alert("no se encontrarón datos");
                    }

                },
                failure: function (data) {
                    alert(data.responseText);
                },
                error: function (data) {
                    alert(data.responseText);
                }

            });
        });
```

and this is what it shows

[image]

I know that it retrieves a record because from the code got the due record in console

[image]

and this is the HTML code

```
<div class="panel panel-primary">

    <div class="panel-heading">
        $.ajax pabletoreto
    </div>

    <div class="panel-body">
        ID: <input type="text" id="busqueda"><br /><br />
        <table class="table table-bordered" id="Table">
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Nombre</th>
                <th>Departamento</th>
                <th>Cargo</th>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2 offset-md-2"><button id="boton_de_pabletoreto">Obtener Todos</button></div>
        <div class="col-md-1"><button id="boton_de_pabletoreto2">Búsqueda</button></div>
    </div>

    <br />
```

I use exactly the same code (except doesn´t need to provide the id value and the due url: "http://localhost:55987/api/Empleados") to retrieve all the records and it works

[image]

Comment: show `console.log(i)` and `console.log(item)` in loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I know that it retrieves a record because from the code got the due record in console

Because you get only one record as a json object (not an array) the [.each()](https://api.jquery.com/each/) iterates on each property (this is your issue....your undefined elements):

```js
var data = {id: 1, Nombres: 'Pablo Ern...', Cargo: 'Gerente', Dpto: 'Contabi...'};
    $.each(data, function (i, item) {
        console.log('Item(' + i + '): ' + item);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

In this case I suggest to avoid to loop and use directly the json object:

```js
var item = {id: 1, Nombres: 'Pablo Ern...', Cargo: 'Gerente', Dpto: 'Contabi...'};
var rows = "<tr>" +
        "<td id='id'>" + item.id + "</td>" +
        "<td id='nombres'>" + item.Nombres + "</td>" +
        "<td id='cargo'>" + item.Cargo + "</td>" +
        "<td id='dpto'>" + item.Dpto + "</td>" +
        "</tr>";
$('#Table').append(rows);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="panel panel-primary">

    <div class="panel-heading">
        $.ajax pabletoreto
    </div>

    <div class="panel-body">
        ID: <input type="text" id="busqueda"><br/><br/>
        <table class="table table-bordered" id="Table">
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Nombre</th>
                <th>Departamento</th>
                <th>Cargo</th>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2 offset-md-2">
            <button id="boton_de_pabletoreto">Obtener Todos</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1">
            <button id="boton_de_pabletoreto2">Búsqueda</button>
        </div>
    </div>

    <br/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that you have wrong `for each loop`:

Change this:

```
$.each(data, function (i, item) { // Here is the error
    var rows = "<tr>" +
        "<td id='id'>" + item.id + "</td>" +
        "<td id='nombres'>" + item.Nombres + "</td>" +
        "<td id='cargo'>" + item.Cargo + "</td>" +
        "<td id='dpto'>" + item.Dpto + "</td>" +
        "</tr>";
    $('#Table').append(rows);
});
```

With this:

```
$.each(data, function (item, i) {
    var rows = "<tr>" +
        "<td id='id'>" + item.id + "</td>" +
        "<td id='nombres'>" + item.Nombres + "</td>" +
        "<td id='cargo'>" + item.Cargo + "</td>" +
        "<td id='dpto'>" + item.Dpto + "</td>" +
        "</tr>";
    $('#Table').append(rows);
});
```

The other error is that `data` is not a list of employees, is an employe. So you are iterating over an object, not a list. Change backend to send a list of employees instead an employe...

Comment: @PabloTobar Edited, tell me

Comment: no need to use the loop.  "<td id='id'>" + data.id + "</td>"